# C++ text file content erased after power loss

Tags: c++, linux, ofstream

I am logging some data into a .txt file during a program execution. The problem is that sometimes I need to cut the power to the system, but I would still like to save the written data.

Here is the code I use to write on the txt file:

```
std::ofstream file; // placed inside the header file

file.open("filename.txt"); // placed in the class constructor

file << "data " << std::endl; // repeatedly called inside a loop
```

The data is flushed during the execution, since I open the file while the program is running and I see the updates. But if I cut the power, the result is an empty file, or only one line written on it.
I've also tried to manually flush(), but that didn't work either.
The OS is Linux Yocto Poky.

Comment: Have you tried manually closing and re-opening the file periodically? While `endl` should flush the stream, which should make it send its content to the underlying file, I'm not sure if it makes it actually *save* the file.

Comment: Where on disk are you storing the file? Beware that some filesystems, such as `/tmp`, are cleared on reboot.

Comment: maybe [fsync](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fsync.html) can help?

Comment: [file.fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) *should* give you the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: @KABoissonneault yes, I tried. And the file is updated with the latest data every time I open it. The problem is only after the power loss

Comment: Are you doing any signal handling? Are you using a UPS?

Comment: @SteveLorimer I am storing the files at the path /logs, that is an existing folder. Does fflush work for ofstream?

Comment: @incBrain Does fsync work for ofstream?

Comment: @pacmaninbw nothing of that.

Comment: The problem is that the OS also needs to commit the file to disk. Typically, the file is cached in memory for performance reasons. You need a solution that allows you to tell the OS to flush as well.

Comment: @charles seems like you need a file descriptor for this and referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558447/retrieving-file-descriptor-from-a-stdfstream) there is no easy way to do it. But maybe you can try to use c-like file writing to figure out if fsync works or not.

Comment: @MicroVirus any hint?

Comment: @charles Not very familiar with that part of Linux myself, but this SO answer seems to be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358431/force-write-of-a-file-to-disk